# Open SSH - issue logging in without password - public key

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords, openssh, public-key

I'm having an issue where I'm unable to login by SSH - I've followed other guides and made sure permissions were set correctly, and that the publickeys on my local machine and remote machine match as well, but it always defaults to the password...

(I'm logging in as a basic user, not root)

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ________________ port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/s/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/s/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/s/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /Users/s/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 88:ea:bd:20:af:78:f8:4f:1f:45:3c:dd:d6:c6:10:dd
debug1: Host '______________' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/s/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/s/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /Users/s/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Can anyone tell me what the issue could be?

Comment: What distribution are you running on the server? Also include in the question the output of `ls -lR ~/.ssh` run on the server.

Comment: output of ls -lR ~/.ssh :

-rw-r--r-- 1 crimeand crimeand 607 Jun 28 23:13 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 crimeand crimeand 608 Jun 28 23:14 id_dsa.pub

Running Red Hat 4.4.7-4

Comment: In the question where you can format it nicely. Is it Red Hat Linux 4.4 or Red Hat *Enterprise* Linux 4.4?

Comment: The last few lines show you trying an RSA private key but using a DSA public key. Have you got an actual RSA public key for the server? Or alternatively, have you got a DSA private key?

Comment: Yes, I generated the public key on my local machine and copied it over to the server - I'm not using a private key

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense -- the kind of keys SSH uses _always_ come in pairs (they'd be quite useless otherwise), and `ssh-keygen` writes two files: one with both private & public parameters (e.g. `id_rsa`), and another with just the public half. (e.g. `id_rsa.pub`)

Comment: Please run on the client: `ssh-keygen -l -f /Users/s/.ssh/id_rsa` and `ssh-keygen -l -f /Users/s/.ssh/id_dsa` , and on the server: `ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 0):

If your `ssh -v` output on the client shows that it's "Offering public key" and then moves on to "Next authentication method: password" without an apparent error, here are a few things to try (these work for me on CentOS and Fedora):

1. If your server `sshd_config` has `StrictModes yes` (usually the default) then you have to obey some permissions rules: on the server, the user home directory can't be writable by group or other (700, 711, or 755 should work), and `~/.ssh` should be 700 and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` should be 600 (both private).
2. If you created the `~/.ssh` directory on the server as a different user, and if your SELinux is in strict mode, it may be getting in the way. On the server, run `restorecon -Rv ~/.ssh` **as the user**, and if it emits some things it changed, that may solve your problem. (This is a good reason to use the `ssh-copy-id` command from the client, so `~/.ssh` is created as the user.)
3. Even if #2 wasn't your issue, SELinux may still be the culprit. Inspect `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for errors... one time I was trying to use SSH to execute a command as a daemon's user whose home directory was under `/var`, and SELinux was denying the ability to read `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in this case.